# How to use lenis-nuxt properly for smooth scroll

Tags: vue.js, scroll, vuejs3, nuxt3

I can't configure lenis-nuxt, is there a way in which i could implement it on my proyect? I tried to use it on app.vue file and layout like this:

```
  <div class="side-bar-layout">
    <div class="page-content-slot">
    <ClientOnly>
      <Lenis>
      <slot />
      </Lenis>
    </ClientOnly>
    </div>
  </div>
```